# Is it possible to control the "back to" button?

Tags: ios

Is it possible for my app to hide the "back to" button that iOS inserts in the top of the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than grabbing the name of your app, no there isn't a way to take over that button.

Its created by the system anytime one app opens another. It grabs just the bundle display name from the sending app. Tapping on it is outside of your application.

You can listen for `didResignActive` and other AppDelegate callbacks to adjust your app probably. But changing its behavior or keying on it specifically isn't possible.